# Match key name and show document in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, key-value

```
Json Structure:
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d6cb28725f3019a5241781"),
        "Number" : {
            "value" : "1234567",
        },
        "DeviceID" : {
            "value" : "01",
        }
        "type" : {
            "value" : "ce06"}
```

Now i want to find only those keys document which start from /dev/.

i tried this script:

```
var cur = db.LIVEDATA.find({"ProductIMEIno.value":"359983007488004"});
  cur.forEach(function(doc){
  var keynames = Object.keys(doc);
  print('the length is '+keynames.length);
  for(var i=0;i<keynames.length;i++){
  if(keynames[i].match(/Dev/)){
  print("the name is "+keynames); }}} )
```

but this is not working properly.

Desired Output;
Only this document should show on the basis of key name search.

```
  "DeviceID" : {
                "value" : "01",
```

Comment: Please describe it properly.  You are saying that you want to find key which start from /dev/ and I'm not able to figure out where that /dev/ in your given example, and to which key you are talking about. And then you added one more flavour by showing the desired output, and I'm not able to find out from where the hell this desired output is generating.

Comment: i m taking about DeviceID .

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB isn't designed to find *keys* dynamically like this; it's much easier to use it to find *values* dynamically, so you could restructure your data structure to allow this:

```json
"_id" : ObjectId("55d6cb28725f3019a5241781"),
"data" : [
    {
        "key" : "Number",
        "value" : "1234567",
    },
    {
        "key": "DeviceID",
        "value" : "01",
    },
    {
        "key" : "type",
        "value" : "ce06"
    }
]
```

Then you will be able to query it like this:

```js
db.LIVEDATA.aggregate([
  {$match: {"ProductIMEIno.value":"359983007488004"}},
  {$unwind: "$data"},
  {$match: {"data.key" : /^dev/i }}
]);
```

That will return data structured like this:

```json
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("55d6cb28725f3019a5241781"),
  "data" : {
    "key" : "DeviceID",
    "value" : "01"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a data collection like this:

```
[
  {
    "Number": {
      "value": "1234567"
    },
    "DeviceID": {
      "value": "01"
    },
    "DeviceID2": {
      "value": "01",
      "name": "abc123"
    },
    "type": {
      "value": "ce06"
    }
  },
  {
    "Number": {
      "value": "1234568"
    },
    "DeviceID": {
      "value": "02"
    },
    "type": {
      "value": "ce07"
    }
  }
]
```

You can use following aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {}
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "root_key_value_list": {
        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$root_key_value_list"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "root_key_value_list.k": {
        "$regex": "^Dev"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "root_key_value_list": {
        "$push": "$root_key_value_list"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "root": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$root_key_value_list"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$root"
    }
  }
])
```

the result will be:

```
[
  {
    "DeviceID": {
      "value": "01"
    },
    "DeviceID2": {
      "name": "abc123",
      "value": "01"
    }
  },
  {
    "DeviceID": {
      "value": "02"
    }
  }
]
```

playground:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/z5EeHALCqzy